# Boton start/pausa

Tags: android

estoy haciendo una aplicación donde habrá varios botones, cada uno reproducirá un audio diferente. 
La reproducción del audio me funciona el problema esta en que si vuelves a apretar el botón no se para, en vez de eso lo que hace es reproducirlo otra vez sin parar la primera reproducción, es decir que si aprieto 3 vece estará sonando 3 veces el mismo audio.
Lo que yo quiero hacer es que al pulsar otra vez el botón o al pulsar otro diferente el que esta sonando se pare

```
public class TarjetaOberta extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btM;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tarjeta_oberta);
    references();
}

private void references(){

    btM = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btMarta);

}

public void Marta(View view){

    MediaPlayer ring= MediaPlayer.create(TarjetaOberta.this,R.raw.marta);
    ring.start();

}
```

Este es el código del botón que tengo creado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

entonces prueba lo siguiente

```
public void Marta(View view){

if(ring.isPlaying)//Si al momento de presionar el boton esta sonando lo detenemos
    ring.stop();//detenemos 
}
else//de lo contrario lo reproducimos
{
 ring.start();//volvemos a iniciar
}
```

Comment: explica por qué este código soluciona el problema

Comment: con esto hay que usar un boolean que indique si esta sonando o no entonces puede funcionar sino no funcionara gracia me has ayudado a encontrarlo

Answer (score 1):

Pues crea la instancia del MediaPlayer como global y antes de reproducir el sonido colocas un stop asi se va a detener la instancia del sonido antes de iniciar el nuevo

```
public class TarjetaOberta extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btM;
 MediaPlayer ring;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tarjeta_oberta);
    references();

  ring= MediaPlayer.create(TarjetaOberta.this,R.raw.marta);// al colocarlo en el onCreate solo es necesario referenciarlo 1 vez
}

private void references(){

    btM = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btMarta);

}

public void Marta(View view){

    ring.stop();//detenemos 

    ring.start();//volvemos a iniciar

}
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda,saludos

Comment: al usar esto no se reproduce el sonido